# Delete directory after file has been copied using a Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files that I will write to within a temp folder. I call a batch file to either copy or move them:

```
@ECHO OFF
move /y %1 %2
EXIT

@ECHO OFF
xcopy /A %1 %2
EXIT
```

How would I call a batch file to check if all of the files have finished copying and there are no other files remaining? Then I would like to delete the folder.

**EDIT:
I figured out by just using a loop to continuously call rmdir will work fine

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
rmdir %1 

if EXIST %1 (
    goto loop
)
EXIT
```

Comment: Both commands `move` and `xcopy` are synchronous, so they're finished moving and copying when they exit.

Comment: NOTE: your `xcopy` command will only copy the files with the Archive attribute set, so it might not copy all of the contens of the folder. And, `xcopy` does not remove the files once copied. So, the `move` approach would be a better election.

Comment: Then, you may be tempted to just add a `rmdir` after the `move` command finishes. But you may experience two scenarios of race conditions where the completion of the command may leave data behind: 1. some file movement might not be produced, because of locking by a second process 2. Some new files might have been created by a second process in that case, the only chance is to rerun the `move` batch.

Comment: To clarify, I am only using either the MOVE or the XCOPY.

Comment: After calling either one of these BAT, I could like to check if no files are moving or copying in order to delete the temp folder

Comment: just invoke `rmdir`. it will remove the folder only if it is empty,

Comment: Yes, but how can I continue to call the RMDIR until the directory is empty?

Comment: so you want to move all the files and then call rmdir?

Comment: Just use `rmdir` once - it will perform the task and then return control to the batch file.  Also, if you use `"%~1"` with the quotes then a batch file will also handle quoted terms for long pathnames and filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This works for you....

```
@echo off

REM Copy all the files from source to target first
xcopy /s source_directory target_directory

REM Check if there are any files of any type inside source_directory,if YES move it to destination and if NOT then delete the directory
dir /b /a "source_directory\*" | >nul findstr "^" && xcopy /s source_directory target_directory || rd <source_directory>
```

Note addition of /a option to enable finding of hidden and system files/folders.